# I am not getting this line of code in Machine Learning

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I have to write this piece of code for the lrcostfunction assignment in the Machine Learning course in coursera. But I still don't understand why

```
theta1 = [0 ; theta(2:end, :)];
```

is written? theta1 means what?

```
h = sigmoid(X * theta)
theta1 = [0 ; theta(2:end, :)];
p = lambda * (theta1' * theta1)/(2 * m);
J = ((-y)'*log(h)-(1-y)'*log(1-h))/m + p;

grad = (X' * (h - y) + lambda * theta1)/ m;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In logistic regression, theta (θ) is a vector representing the parameters (or weights) of the linear function of x.

[image]

Now, given a training set, one method to learn the parameters theta (θ) is to be to make h(x) close to y, at least for the training examples we have. This is defined using a **cost function or the error function** (J(θ)), for each value of the θ, which we want to minimize.

[image]

The first theta1 parameter is initialized as zero. Later using gradient descent, next theta parameter is computed. In gradient descent, the J(θ) parameter is calculated using partial differentiation as we want to minimize it.

[image]

Here \alpha is learning rate with which gradient descent algorithm runs. It starts with an initial value in the array - theta1 as zero and then, next value is calculated using the above equation. and so on for other theta parameters.

EDIT:

Explaining the code:

`theta1 = [0 ; theta(2:end, :)];`

The above code is MATLAB code. Here theta1 is an Array (vector or matrix representation). It is created using *horizontal* concatenation of two fields.

- 1) `0`
- 2) `theta(2:end, :)`

First, is a scalar value `0`

Second, this means that take all values as it is, except the first row from the array `theta`. (Note theta is input array to `LRCOSTFUNCTION(theta, X, y, lambda)`)

Comment: Mam, what does this mean? [0 ; theta(2:end, :)]

Comment: @Shuvamchatterjee Updated my answer. Hope this helps!